# how should I solve this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve this?
$$y^\prime = y^2 -4$$
I think I am supposed to use the separable equations method and then use partial fractions.

Comment: :yes firstly separate and then use method of partial fraction
you are right

Comment: Why don't you try, then ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2-4$$
$$\int\frac{dy}{y^2-4}=\int dx$$

Now: $$\int \frac{dt}{t^2-a^2}=\frac{1}{2a}\ln\frac{x+a}{x-a}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2-4$$

Then you should use separation of variables giving you

$$\int\frac{dy}{y^2-4}=\int dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

You've got $$\frac{dy}{dt}=y^2-4\Leftrightarrow 1\cdot dt = \frac{dt}{y^2-4} \ dy.$$ This will yeild the integrals $$\int1\ dt=\int\frac{1}{y^2-4} \ dy.$$ Assuming you know how to integrate integrals of the form in the HRS, you will get $$t+C_1 = \frac{\ln|y-2|-\ln|y+2|}{4}+C_2.$$ Now go ahead and solve for $y$ and bake together the constants.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2-4$$
$$\int\frac{dy}{y^2-4}=\int dx$$

$$ \frac12 \tanh^{-1}{(y/2)}=x $$